# When notified for INTERNET_STATUS_COOKIE_SENT, DWORD(lpvStatusInformation) does not return cookie count

Tags: delphi, winapi, cookies, wininet, delphi-xe7

Microsoft says that whenever InternetStatusCallback() notifies for event INTERNET_STATUS_COOKIE_SENT the lpvStatusInformation is DWORD holding the number of cookies

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385121.aspx

I receive too big number - 260558716.

```
procedure THttpClient.Get(const Url: TUrl);
var
  hInet: HINTERNET;
  Context: INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK;
begin
  hInet := InternetOpen(PWideChar('Some user agent'), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  InternetSetOption(hInet, INTERNET_OPTION_CONTEXT_VALUE, Self, SizeOf(Self));
  Context := InternetSetStatusCallback(hInet, INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK(@DoWinInetCallback));
  ...
end;

procedure DoWinInetCallback(hInet: HINTERNET; dwContext: DWORD;
  dwInternetStatus: DWORD; lpvStatusInformation: Pointer;
  dwStatusInformationLength: DWORD); stdcall;

  procedure Notify(const Text: string);
  var
    P: Pointer;
    HC: THttpClient;
  begin
    // when the handle is creted or closed dwContext is invalid
    if not (dwInternetStatus in [INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED, INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING]) then
    begin
      P := Pointer(dwContext);
      HC := THttpClient(P);
      HC.FErrorCode := dwInternetStatus;
      HC.FErrorDescription:= Text;
      HC.RaiseStatus;
    end;
  end;

begin
  ...
  // Indicates the number of cookies that were either sent or suppressed, when a
  // request is sent. The lpvStatusInformation parameter is a DWORD with the
  // number of cookies sent or suppressed.
  INTERNET_STATUS_COOKIE_SENT: // 320
    Notify(Format('Number of cookies sent or suppressed when sending the request were %0:d.', [DWORD(lpvStatusInformation)]));
  // Indicates the number of cookies that were accepted, rejected, downgraded
  // (changed from persistent to session cookies), or leashed (will be sent out
  // only in 1st party context). The lpvStatusInformation parameter is a DWORD
  // with the number of cookies received.
  INTERNET_STATUS_COOKIE_RECEIVED: // 321
    Notify(Format('Number of cookies that were accepted, rejected, downgraded (changed from persistent to session cookies), or leashed (will be sent out only in 1st party context) was %0:d.', [DWORD(lpvStatusInformation)]));
  ...
  else
    Notify(Format('Unknown status code. Code: %0:d', [dwInternetStatus]));
  end;
end;
```

Is there a way to get the number of cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is misleading.  `lpvStatusInformation` is actually a **pointer to** a `DWORD`:

```
// Indicates the number of cookies that were either sent or suppressed, when a
// request is sent. The lpvStatusInformation parameter is a pointer to a DWORD
// with the number of cookies sent or suppressed.
INTERNET_STATUS_COOKIE_SENT: // 320
  Notify(Format('Number of cookies sent or suppressed when sending the request were %0:d.', [PDWORD(lpvStatusInformation)^]));
// Indicates the number of cookies that were accepted, rejected, downgraded
// (changed from persistent to session cookies), or leashed (will be sent out
// only in 1st party context). The lpvStatusInformation parameter is a pointer
// to a DWORD with the number of cookies received.
INTERNET_STATUS_COOKIE_RECEIVED: // 321
  Notify(Format('Number of cookies that were accepted, rejected, downgraded (changed from persistent to session cookies), or leashed (will be sent out only in 1st party context) was %0:d.', [PDWORD(lpvStatusInformation)^]));
```

Comment: It worked. Again I am deeply impressed with the depth of your knowledge.